# Well-definedness of ADM mass, energy, linear and angular momentum

Tags: differential-geometry, asymptotics, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

In asymptotically flat initial data sets, one can define the ADM mass, energy, linear and angular momenta via spatial limits of integrals over 2-spheres.

My questions are:

Is asymptotical flatness enough to ensure that the ADM mass, energy and linear momentum converge? (I know that for the angular momentum, that is not true). Does convergence of one of them imply convergence of the others?

And regarding the angular momentum, is being asymptotically Euclidean enough?
(Chrúsciel obtained some fall-off rates in his work in 1987 that ensure finiteness of the ADM angular momentum, but they are stronger than asymptotically Euclidean.)

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the decay rates of the metric components that you assume. I can't remember the exact results (and I am not at all familiar with the proofs) but I believe if they fall off like $r^{-2}$ then all three are well defined. L. Bieri proved a generalization, and I believe she showed that if we assume $r^{-1}$ decay then one of these three is well defined.

Comment: I believe you need to assume some fall-of rates, otherwise you could have the metric decaying as slow as you like.

Comment: Asymptotical flatness is defined over some fall-off rates of the metric and second fundamental form components. My question is whether they are enough to ensure convergence of the integrals in the mass, energy and linear momentum definition (as that is not the case for the angular momentum for example).

Comment: Maybe this (Section 3.2) addresses your questions: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.5429.pdf. It looks like if you assume that the metric decays as $r^{-1}$, its derivatives and the second fundamental form decay as $r^{-2}$, and the second fundamental form decays like $r^{-3}$, then all but the angular momentum are well-defined. Remarks 3 and 4 note that the other quantities are finite under the assumption of these decay rates.

Comment: Thanks, that paper is very helpful!